# How do I create arrays from array in this case

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create multiple arrays of objects with each keys inside the object.

How can I generate my expected output (shown below the initial array)?

Initial array:

```
[{
    title: 'Linus tech tips',
    name: 'Linus',
    id: 'SA946',
  },
  {
    title: 'Linus tech tips',
    name: 'Colton',
    id: 'SA947',
  }
];
```

Expected output:

```
[{
  text: 'Linus tech tips',
}, {
  text: 'Linus',
}, {
  text: 'SA946',
}, ],

[{
  text: 'Linus tech tips',
}, {
  text: 'Colton',
}, {
  text: 'SA947',
}, ],
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to add your code? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Ethan thanks for the response.I have tried map but i couldn't get it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array.map` to achieve that. Please have a look:

```js
const initial = [
  {
    title: 'Linus tech tips',
    name: 'Linus',
    id: 'SA946',
  },
  {
    title: 'Linus tech tips',
    name: 'Colton',
    id: 'SA947',
  },
];

const expected = initial.map(
  (item) => Object.values(item).map(
    (itemValue) => ({ text: itemValue }),
  ),
);

console.log(expected);
```

Comment: @ Thanks for the response.Work flawless

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the keys, then flatten the array.

```js
[{
title: 'Linus tech tips',
name: 'Linus',
id: 'SA946',
},
{
title: 'Linus tech tips',
name: 'Colton',
id: 'SA947',
}].map(
    item => {
        return Object.keys(item).map(
            key => {
                return {text: item[key]}
            }
        )
    }
).flat()
```

```
[
  {
    "text": "Linus tech tips"
  },
  {
    "text": "Linus"
  },
  {
    "text": "SA946"
  },
  {
    "text": "Linus tech tips"
  },
  {
    "text": "Colton"
  },
  {
    "text": "SA947"
  }
]
```

Or, if you want to have the items separated, do not use `flat()` at the end:

```
[
  [
    {
      "text": "Linus tech tips"
    },
    {
      "text": "Linus"
    },
    {
      "text": "SA946"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "text": "Linus tech tips"
    },
    {
      "text": "Colton"
    },
    {
      "text": "SA947"
    }
  ]
]
```